# Navigation bar disappears on zoom/mobile devices

Tags: mobile, navigation, zooming

Coding isn't my strongest point, noticed on mobile devices and zooming on browsers that the main nav bar disappears.

http://kizzme.co.uk/index.html

Any help appreciated!

Kizz

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS you are hiding the navbar on mobile with out showing a mobile nav ,

to show the nav any way add

```
  #nav {display: block !important;}
```

to the end of this file `http://kizzme.co.uk/css/lessframework.css`

or if you want to make a mobile navbar

check this  `http://navnav.co/`